# Change from hour minute second to second from string

Tags: java, android, string, substring

Now,I have a string  String time= "200hour 0minute 0second"
I want to track numbers in string and convert to second..As above string..I want to get value 200*3600..
My code:

```
    //change from hour minute to second
public String changeSecond(String time)
{
    String result;
    int ind_hour=time.indexOf("hour");
    int ind_minute=time.indexOf("minute");
    int ind_second=time.indexOf("second");

    int hour=Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, ind_hour));
    int minute=Integer.parseInt(time.substring(ind_hour+1, ind_minute));;
    int second=Integer.parseInt(time.substring(ind_minute+1, ind_second));

    result=String.valueOf(hour*3600+minute*60+second);

    return result;
}
```

but when i run changeSecond(time).It don't work..How must I do.

Comment: Don't do it this way. It will be prone to bugs. Can't you just pass the hours, minutes, and seconds as integers?

Comment: What exactly does not work ?

Comment: Use `String.split();` for each string you want to extract.

Comment: int minute=Integer.parseInt(time.substring(ind_hour+1+"hour".length(), ind_minute));  ?

Comment: Actually I think using split() is better.
int hour = time.split("hour")[0];
int minute= time.split("hour")[1].splite("minute")[0];
......

Something like this??

Comment: I  used the way of Jeff Lee and it worked well.Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make changes to the following lines:

```
int hour=Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, ind_hour));
int minute=Integer.parseInt(time.substring(ind_hour+5, ind_minute));
int second=Integer.parseInt(time.substring(ind_minute+7, ind_second));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String changeSecond(String time)
{
    String result;
int ind_hour=time.indexOf("hour");
int ind_minute=time.indexOf("minute");
int ind_second=time.indexOf("second");

int hour=Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, ind_hour));
int minute=Integer.parseInt(time.substring(ind_hour+6, ind_minute));; // value 6 is length of minute 
int second=Integer.parseInt(time.substring(ind_minute+6, ind_second));

  int totalsec=((hour*60*60)+(minute*60)+second);
   result=String.valueOf(totalsec);

return result;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Its not the way to do it.But It will work.Try this,

```
String hour="200hour 0minute 0second";

     String[] secondarray=hour.split("hour");

     String second=secondarray[0]; //here "second" will have the value 200
```

Comment: I want to get both minute and second..:(

Answer (score 0):

You can split the tab into 3 parts : One will contains the hours, another the minutes and the last one the seconds.

```
public static String changeSecond(String time)
    {
        String tab[] = time.split(" ");
        String result = "";
        int ind_hour=tab[0].indexOf("hour");
        int ind_minute=tab[1].indexOf("minute");
        int ind_second=tab[2].indexOf("second");

        int hour=Integer.parseInt(tab[0].substring(0, ind_hour));
        int minute=Integer.parseInt(tab[1].substring(0, ind_minute));
        int second=Integer.parseInt(tab[2].substring(0, ind_second));

        result=String.valueOf(hour*3600+minute*60+second);

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest solution I could come up with.  Just split on " " then remove the text that's irrelevant.

```
public String changeSecond(final String time)
{
    final String[] times = time.split(" ");
    final int hour = Integer.parseInt(times[0].replace("hour", ""));
    final int minute = Integer.parseInt(times[1].replace("minute", ""));
    final int second = Integer.parseInt(times[2].replace("second", ""));
    return String.valueOf(hour*3600+minute*60+second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial code was throwing parsing errors since alpha characters were being passed to the `Integer.parseInt` method.  The alpha characters were being included because the substring did not take into account the length of the terms hour, minute and second.  I would recommend splitting the string to tidy things up.

```
public String changeSecond(String time) {
    String[] tokens = time.split(" ");
    tokens[0] = tokens[0].substring(0, tokens[0].indexOf("hour"));
    tokens[1] = tokens[1].substring(0, tokens[1].indexOf("minute"));
    tokens[2] = tokens[2].substring(0, tokens[2].indexOf("second"));

    return String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]) * 3600
            + Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your hours,minutes and seconds parsing as:

```
        int hour=Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, ind_hour));
        int minute=Integer.parseInt(time.substring(ind_hour + "hour".length() + 1, ind_minute));
        int second=Integer.parseInt(time.substring(ind_minute + "minute".length() + 1, ind_second));
```